# Finding The Odds Of Two Specific Items Being Selecte

Tags: probability

Scenario: I have a list of $30$ items like the following:

$A_1
A_2
\ldots
A_{30}$

The list is randomized so all items are in a different order. Once an item is selected, it is removed from the list.

What are the odds of two specific items being chosen $1st$ and $2nd$?

Comment: Well, what are the chances that one of those two items will be chosen first? And given that one of those two items is chosen first, what are the chances that the other item will be chosen second? So, what do you conclude?

Comment: Not sure. That’s why I asked the question. I don’t think it’s as simple as 1/30 and then 1/29 because I want to know the odds of two SPECIFIC items being chosen from the list. For example what are the odds of A1 being chosen first and then A2 being chosen second. The list is completely randomized before each item is selected.

Comment: Why would it not be as simple as 1/30 and then 1/29?

Answer (score 4):

Let these two specific items be $A_i$ and $A_j$.

I assume that ``the list is completely randomized'' means that each item has equal probability to be selected.

In particular, the item $A_i$ has probability $\frac 1{30}$ to be selected first.

Next, if the item $A_i$ was selected, the list is completely randomized again, and so each remaining item has equal probability to be selected.

In particular, the item $A_j$ has probability $\frac 1{29}$ to be selected second, after the item $A_i$ was already selected first.

Thus the probability that the item $A_i$ was selected first and then the item $A_j$ was selected second is $\frac 1{30}\cdot \frac 1{29}$.